MS Access - Add extra line space between the control in either query or subreport prior to export to MS Word
Long title but explains it...I've created a video database that works great and also includes a citation process. I created queries to concatenate all the needed citation information per guidelines and use on each image, slide, etc.
I split the citations into groups (categories) and created a main report with subreports that segments off the groups -- but -- I need to have a space between each "citation" control, either in each of the queries, in each subreport, or in the code when I export to MS Word...
The reason being is I use MS word and copy/paste the info into my credit roll program -- but I can't get them to separate -- I need 2 lines between groups and 1 line between citations.
If not spaced it's a pain to go through...
Example attached.
Thanks in advance for any help!

Lisa B.

In the query I did test:
c_return: [Citation] & Chr(10)
didn't work...
cn: [Citation] & Chr(13) & Chr(10)
didn't work...
ug!
